# 公開されてるリポジトリに独自修正を加えて管理するための git 上の操作方法

Tags: git

いままで自分で１から作ったものしか git であつかったことがなく

clone branch commit merge push

のサイクルぐらいしかわからない前提で聞いて欲しいです

---

外部で git で公開されているものを一部機能改修して使いたいと思ってます
この場合どういう手順で管理すればいいのでしょうか

単に clone しただけでは何かの拍子で push コマンドをうっちゃったときに
本家にリクエストが飛んでしまうのが怖いのでなるべく本家のリモート情報は残したくないです

※ 本家に貢献する気がない分けではなくビジネスロジックやパスワード等機密情報をコミットに入れてしまった場合に情報漏洩等を防ぎたいからでバグ等をみつけたら別途報告等はするつもりです

clone して .git を削除して git init しなおしてから
feature branch なりをきって修正入れて自分のリポジトリに push

みたいなことをやると本家のコミット履歴を所持していないため
本家で改修があったときにそれをとりこむことができない気がするんですが方法ってありますか？

あるいは本家のコミット履歴を保持したまま
独自修正ブランチを切ってそのブランチだけリモートブランチを自分のリポジトリにするみたいなことってできるんでしょうか

---

[公開されてるリポジトリに独自修正を加えて管理する方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/83317/%e5%85%ac%e9%96%8b%e3%81%95%e3%82%8c%e3%81%a6%e3%82%8b%e3%83%aa%e3%83%9d%e3%82%b8%e3%83%88%e3%83%aa%e3%81%ab%e7%8b%ac%e8%87%aa%e4%bf%ae%e6%ad%a3%e3%82%92%e5%8a%a0%e3%81%88%e3%81%a6%e7%ae%a1%e7%90%86%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e6%96%b9%e6%b3%95)
こちらで同様の質問をしたところ fork を使えばいいという回答を頂いたんですが
ためしに本家リポジトリで fork ボタンを押してみたところ github のアカウント画面にとばされます

使っているリモートリポジトリサービスは bitbucket なんですがどういう git 操作を行えば実現できるのでしょうか

Comment: 次の投稿はあなたの質問の回答になりますか？ [公開されてるリポジトリに独自修正を加えて管理する方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/83317/%e5%85%ac%e9%96%8b%e3%81%95%e3%82%8c%e3%81%a6%e3%82%8b%e3%83%aa%e3%83%9d%e3%82%b8%e3%83%88%e3%83%aa%e3%81%ab%e7%8b%ac%e8%87%aa%e4%bf%ae%e6%ad%a3%e3%82%92%e5%8a%a0%e3%81%88%e3%81%a6%e7%ae%a1%e7%90%86%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e6%96%b9%e6%b3%95)

Comment: 自分がした同じ質問もともと git の機能上の話をききたかったのですがなぜかリモートリポジトリサービスの機能の話になってしまって質問を分けてくださいと言われたので別にしてしまいました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「外部で git で公開されているもの」というのが、自分の所有するレポジトリではなく、`https`経由でクローンしており自分のアカウントが書き込み権限を持っていないというのであれば、`push`しても失敗しますので問題ないかと思います。

それでも念のため、あるいは書き込み権限があるという場合は、[Git: Set up a fetch-only remote? の解答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7556269/9105334) のように、`no-pushing`など無効な名前を`push`先として指定することができます（当然、`git push`は失敗します）。

```sh
git remote set-url --push origin no-pushing
```

Comment: origin を自分の bitbucket にしようとしてたんですが、確かに本家にあるものはおかないほうが被らなくていい気がします。あと remote add で別のタグを追加することはできたんですが set-url で直接 .git いじらずにおきかえできるんですね。やってみたら git remote -v の表示が変わったのでやりたいことができそうです。ありがとうございました。